# What is the good coding approach incase of multiple if else condition scenarios in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement

```
//Current code without the requirment
void Process(Employee emp)
{
    validateemp(emp);
    updateempname(emp);
    updateempaddress(emp);
    updateempaccess(emp);
}


Code 1:

void Process(Employee emp)
{
    if(emp.Emptype == "Permanent")
    {
        validateemp(emp);
    }
    else
    {
       ValidateContractEmp(emp); 
    }
    
    updateempdetails(emp);
    updateempaddress(emp);
    if(emp.Emptype == "Permanent")
    {
        updateempaccess(emp);
    }
    else
    {
        updateContractempaccess(emp);
    }
}

Code 2: 

void Process(Employee emp)
{
    if(emp.Emptype == "Permanent")
    {
        validateemp(emp);
        updateempdetails(emp);
        updateempaddress(emp);
        updateempaccess(emp);
    }
    else
    {
       ValidateContractEmp(emp); 
       updateempdetails(emp);
       updateempaddress(emp);
       updateContractempaccess(emp);
    }
    
}
```

The first part is the production code. As part of the process we have to validate the emp then update the empdetails, address and then provide access. I have listed just 4 methods, like this we have to do 3 more actions in the process method. We have got a new requirement to include contract employee details along with the permanent employees. So we have to change the logic and introduce new methods to handle the new requirement. My query is what is the good approach code 1 or code 2?  which is better in performance and why?

Comment: For performance, benchamrk it with some test case  that is a real case. Several factors can affect this. On complexity analysis, both seem equally performant.

Comment: On coding style, you could also have the methods like validateemp(emp) updateemp(emp) and the other coded as `virtual`, as part of Employee class, and override them in a PermanentEmployee subclass... this may or may not be helpful, but would avoid doing some "if", and would be a design for other specific treatment, without getting into a bug if else if else if. ..

Comment: The real danger in this code is the `Emptype` string variable - perhaps an enum is more likely to be robust - and also firing off four `void` methods - it seems you are relying on exceptions for error handling.

Comment: @Enigmativity, yes will be changing the Emptype to enum

Comment: And performance is exceedingly unlikely to be impacted at all by either approach. Focus on elegant, maintainable code, and only then on performance when you have a performance problem.

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner and more hygenic approach is to factor out the contents of the if/else statements into separate methods, so you will have:

- a method for updating a contract employee
- a method for updating a permanent employee

This not only encapsulates the relevant functionality for each employee type, it also makes the code easier to maintain and far more unit testable. You will still get a certain amount of duplicated code, but you can't necessarily avoid that; as you've seen, attempting to avoid that can lead to code that has more if/else statements and higher [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).

```
void Process(Employee emp)
{
    if(emp.Emptype == "Permanent")
        UpdatePermanentEmployee(emp);
    else
        UpdateContractEmployee(emp);
}

private void UpdateContractEmployee(Employee emp)
{
   ValidateContractEmp(emp); 
   updateempdetails(emp);
   updateempaddress(emp);
   updateContractempaccess(emp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second approach leads to copy&pasting code, and forgetting to update at least one of the branches during maintenance, especially if you keep adding cases.

The first approach at least follows the basic DRY principle. It just has a bunch of other problems, like using strings instead of enums, no exhaustive defensive code (`else throw NotImplementedException();`), bad naming conventions, etc etc.